# how to find out the third party process popup a screen saver?

Tags: screensaver

Some third party software pops up a screensaver in win10.
It's hard to figure out which process is doing this because when I try to use some tools to analyze it, the screensaver disappears. There is so much software installed on the system that it is hard to analyze each process one by one.
I would like to know if there is any better way to catch it.

Comment: You may have installed something (nothing like this on my systems).  Scan fully with Windows Defender to look for viruses.

Comment: @John Thanks. I tried windows defender, but it report nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed software (or went to a site that installed software) it may be difficult to find.

Your first try with Windows Defender did not find anything.

Try the following:

(1) Again try Windows Defender, except this time, scan in Offline Mode.

[image: Defender Offline Scan]

(2) Scan with MalwareBytes to see if it detects a virus.

(3) Get Autoruns (Microsoft SysInternal), install and run. Look for a Startup Item that may reflect the pop up screen saver.

[image: Autoruns]